# How to create an instance of an associated model when using a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I have two models (Called *User* and *Plan*) that I have associated by using a has_many :through association (called *Participation*). A plan should be created by a user and therefore I want to know:

How to create an  instance of the model *Plan* and an an instance of the join model *Participation* by accessing the create method through an instance of the model *User*

At the moment i am just trying to get it to work in rails console but of course I want to use the functionality in my application. I don't use a HABTM association because the next step is to add an attribute to the relation.

I am able to access existing instances of Plan by entering

```
 > User.first.plans.all
```

in to Rails console. but when I try either

```
> User.first.plan.new
```

or

```
> User.first.plans.new
```

or

```
> User.first.plan.create
```

or

```
> User.first.plans.create
```

I get an error that states

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `plan' for #<User:
```

or

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `plans' for #<User:
```

Extra info:
corresponding models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :participations            #, :foreign_key => ":user_id"
  has_many :plans, :through => :participations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations, :plans

end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :participations            #, :foreign_key => ":plan_id"
  has_many :users, :through => :participations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations, :users

end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user            #, inverse_of: :participations
  belongs_to :plan            #, inverse_of: :participations

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :plan_id, presence: true

end
```

schema is:

```
  create_table "participations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",    null: false
    t.integer  "plan_id",    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "participations", ["plan_id"], name: "index_participations_on_plan_id", using: :btree
  add_index "participations", ["user_id"], name: "index_participations_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "plan_type"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "plans", ["parent_id"], name: "index_plans_on_parent_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username",                            null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: Looks right to me and it's strange that ```User.first.plans.all``` works but ```User.first.plans.create(some_attr: "foo")``` doesn't. I think it's worth asking **are you sure you're using rails 4.2?**

Comment: I can't get my head around it either. But `rails -v` and `bundle show rails` return `Rails 4.2.2` and `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rails-4.2.2` in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This morning I was able to use `User.first.plans.new` and `User.first.plans.create` to create a new instance of Plan. My only guess is that restarting rails console did the trick. I am positive I did that before I posted the above question.

@ MilesStanfield: Thanx! Because of your comment I double checked everything. After doing this I thought to give another try.